How to prove the derivative of $x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ is not in $L^1\left([-1,1]\right)$?
I want to prove $2x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+\frac{2}{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$, which is the derivative of $x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$, is not in $L^1\left([-1,1]\right)$.
I've already changed variables by $u=\frac{1}{x}$, and I want to use the fact that $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin(x)|}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\infty$, but I fail to do the estimation.
Is there another way of solving the problem or how should I continue in this way?

This way is fine. The "fact you want to use" proves that $\frac1x\sin(1/x^2)\notin L^1([-1,1])$, and you are done. So, what is your question?

@AnneBauval Maybe the question is now converted into if $f\in L^1$ and $g\notin L^1$, then $f+g\notin L^1$. This maybe a silly question, but it's not trivial to me.

It should be obvious to you that if $f$ and $h\in L^1$ then $h-f\in L^1$. Apply it to $h=f+g$ and reason by contradiction.

@AnneBauval Oh, that's true. Thanks! :-)
